# Add HSTS header with ssl-passthrough annotation added in Nginx Ingress

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have Nginx-Ingress which has ssl-passthrough annotation added to pass the connection as is to the server but, now this is removing HSTS header from responses which are enabled by default in Ingress.

Based on documentation it looks like ssl-passthrough will remove all other annotations as shown in below URL.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#ssl-passthrough

> "attention Because SSL Passthrough works on layer 4 of the OSI model (TCP) and not on the layer 7 (HTTP), using SSL Passthrough invalidates all the other annotations set on an Ingress object."

I tried these 2 solutions as mentioned in below URL, but did not work.

[Kubernetes ingress not enforcing inserting hsts into headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761430/kubernetes-ingress-not-enforcing-inserting-hsts-into-headers)

1. nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/hsts: "true"
2. nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
   more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=315; includeSubDomains; preload";
3. nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/hsts: "365"

How can I have both of these in this scenario?